# Log in to multiple social accounts like FaceBook, Twitter, Instagram, LinkedIn from a single android app, similar to apps like HootSuite

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, instagram, linkedin-api

I want a user to login to multiple accounts on FaceBook,Twitter,Instagram,LinkedIn,Pinterest,etc. HootSuite and other apps like Parallel Space, Buffer etc. are providing the user to login to multiple accounts from a single application. So say a user has 4 fb accounts, so he can login to his 4 accounts from the same app. How can I achieve the same behavior inside my app?

Facebook logs in the user who is already logged in to the fb official app (if the app is installed) but to allow login from another account, I have to log out of the fb app and login via different account. But I want the user to login to multiple accounts from inside my app without logging out.

Have spent a long time finding a way to achieve this, any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: _“So say a user has 4 fb accounts”_ … then they would be in violation of Facebook terms, because they are only allowed to have one personal account in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe Ok lets say a user has two accounts on Facebook, one personal and one business/fan account, then how to do that?

Comment: Only personal accounts can log into Facebook apps.

Comment: But Hootsuite and such similar apps are doing that, how?